# RCpp/RInside C++ main method queries and limitations?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

A couple question about RInside I could not find on the RCpp mailing list. Can you define the RInside() outside out the C++ main() method? Are there any examples of that? Or can I only have one R embedded session in each C++ application?  IS there a way I could use my C++ papp to call multiple R scripts at the same time through something like OpenMP?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can define your `RInside()` instance wherever you want.

But you are limited to have *exactly one* instance per process because R is single-threaded.  So I find instantiating in `main()` easiest as I can then pass a reference around.  See the various example scripts in the package.

And yes, if you want "many" instances, the trick of spawning distinct *processes* via MPI is a good one.

As for OpenMP, I found that you have to be *very* careful because of the singlethreadedness of R.

But why don't you just try want you want to try and report back on the rcpp-devel list if it fails?

Comment: Hi Dirk: I am looking at the various C++ samples but the RInside seems to be defined in main()? Do you have any you can refer me to any specific examples where RInside() is defined outside of main()?  I also looked at the MPI ones but trying to make head and tails out of it. Thanks

Comment: Please re-read what I wrote, I did not claim I had examples for you _because I like to put this in main_.  But eg when I wrote the Qt example, I also experimented with putting it elsewhere.  Your code, your pick.